# Problems with Self-hosting a WCF service

Tags: wcf, .net-4.0

I have been evaluating whether to selfhost a wcf service in a windows service or IIS/asp.net

I am wondering what real world problems have you run into when self hosting WCF.

Answer (score 3):

Why is it you (and a great many other folks, too) are instantly assuming self-hosting would cause problems (or more problems than hosting in IIS) ??

We're using a bunch of self-hosted WCF services (inside Windows NT Services) almost exclusively, and I wouldn't want to have it any other way. For any *serious* production-ready hosting, I would *always* recommend self-hosting first.

**Why?**

- I can **fully control** the URL for the service - no IIS forcing server name, virtual directory, port, and an *.svc file on me
- I can **start and stop** those services at will, which is extremely useful in many scenarios
- I have **full support for all bindings** and protocols - no fuss, no muss - it just works
- I don't have to deal with application pool, app pool recycling and other annoyances of IIS

So again: **why** do you automatically assume self-hosting is going to cause problems?? It will actually prevent quite a few IIS issues!

Comment: Actually I prefer the idea of self hosting.  I just don't like ms documentation of when to pick a hosting method.  I also don't want to get blind sided by an oversight.

Answer (score 0):

I would say, this is mainly driven by your transport protocol.

If you use TCP or named-pipes, I will advocate self-hosting (yes I know IIS can do but I would like the flexibility of self-hosting). For HTTP however, I believe IIS is the way to go since it covers a lot of issues that would be a lot of work to implement in self-hosting.

Self-hosting a TCP or named-pipe service is quick and easy, no special gotchas there. Only on named-pipes, I must say [named pipe hardening](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb757001.aspx) on Windows Vista/7/2008 has made the model much more complex and for me, pretty unusable.